# How to Autoincrement the Column index number by dragging VLOOKUP formula down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I need to drag a Vlookup down and have the Column index number in to increase by 1 every row I drag it down.

So for example:
Row 1:

```
IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,**35**,0)<=0,"IGNORE",VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,**35**,0))
```

I need row 2 to be:

```
IF(VLOOKUP(A3,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,**36**,0)<=0,"IGNORE",VLOOKUP(A3,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,**36**,0))
```

The bold 35 is what I need to autoincrement just like how the A2 becomes A3 for the lookup value Autoincrements. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Try: `=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(A35),0)<=0,"IGNORE",VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(A35),0))` in place of `A35` you can use `ZZ35` so as to avoid confusion on using or referencing the column A

Comment: Replace `35` with `ROWS($A$1:$A35)` and fill down.

Answer (score 1):

As commented above I will be looking at using the `ROW()` function in Excel, since it returns the row number for a reference. Like for example, `ROW(A35)` returns `35` as it is the `35`th row in the spreadsheet, therefore when its dragged down, it becomes `ROW(A36)` which represents the `36`th row in the spreadsheet. Therefore, as stated above, we can use the following formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(A35),0)<=0,"IGNORE",VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(A35),0))
```

---

Or,

To avoid confusion in using the `Column A` as it may or may not contain some other data, hence we can use the `Column ZZ`.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(ZZ35),0)<=0,"IGNORE",VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(ZZ35),0))
```

---

or If one having access to `MS365` or `Excel 2021` can use the `LET()`

```
=LET(x, VLOOKUP(A2,'Jan 2024'!$D:$BP,ROW(A35),0), IF(x<=0,"IGNORE",x))
```

---